# int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring

i am creating the Spring boot project using student and task using one to one relationship.i ran into the problem i attached below.while i add the new task i got the problem.what i tried so far i attached below

```
 023-07-22 08:38:31.269  WARN 3500 --- [nio-8070-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.SpringAppliction.entity.Student` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.SpringAppliction.entity.Student` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1)<EOL> at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 6, column: 21] (through reference chain: com.example.SpringAppliction.dto.TaskSaveDTO["student"])]
```

**task Controller**

```
  @PostMapping(path ="save")
    public String saveTask(@RequestBody TaskSaveDTO taskSaveDTO)
    {
        String id = taskService.addTask(taskSaveDTO);
        return id;
    }
```

**Entity**
**Task**

```
@Id
@Column(name = "task_id", length = 50)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int taskid;

@Column(name="task_name")
private String taskname;

@Column(name="description")
private String description;

@Column(name="complete")
private Boolean complete;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
private Student student;
```

**TaskSaveDTO**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class TaskSaveDTO {

    private String taskname;

    private String description;

    private Boolean complete;

    private Student student;
}
```

**TaskService**

```
public interface TaskService {

      String addTask(TaskSaveDTO taskSaveDTO);

}
```

**TaskServiceIMPL**

```
public String addTask(TaskSaveDTO taskSaveDTO) {

    Task task = new Task(
            taskSaveDTO.getTaskname(),
            taskSaveDTO.getDescription(),
            taskSaveDTO.getComplete(),
            taskSaveDTO.getStudent()

    );

    taskRepo.save(task);
    return task.getTaskname();
}
```

**Entity**
**Student**

```
   @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="student_id", length = 50)
    private Long  studentid;

    @Column(name="student_name", length = 50)
    private String studentname;

    @Column(name="address", length = 70)
    private String address;

    @Column(name="mobile", length = 12)
    private int mobile;

    @Column(name="activestate", columnDefinition = "TINYINT default 1")
    private boolean activestate;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "student")

    private Task task;
```

**StudentSaveDTO**

```
public class StudentSaveDTO {

    private Long studentid;
    private String studentname;
    private String address;
    private int mobile;
    private boolean activestate;

}
```

i attached student entity and studentDTO as well

**StudentServiceIMPL**

```
  @Override
        public String addStudent(StudentSaveDTO studentSaveDTO) {
    
            Student student = new Student(
                    studentSaveDTO.getStudentname(),
                    studentSaveDTO.getAddress(),
                    studentSaveDTO.getMobile(),
                    studentSaveDTO.isActivestate()
            );
    
            studentRepo.save(student);
            return student.getStudentname();
        }
```

**studentcontroller**
**StudentController**

```
@PostMapping(path ="save")
public String saveStudent(@RequestBody StudentSaveDTO studentSaveDTO)
{
    String id = studentService.addStudent(studentSaveDTO);
    return id;
}
```

**StudentRepo**

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Repository
public interface StudentRepo extends JpaRepository<Student,Long > {
}
```

**TaskRepo**

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Repository
public interface TaskRepo extends JpaRepository<Task,Long > {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TaskSaveDTO**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class TaskSaveDTO {

    private String taskname;

    private String description;

    private Boolean complete;

    private long studentId;
}
```

**StudentService**

```
 public interface StudentService {

      String addStudent(StudentSaveDTO studentSaveDTO);

      Student getStudent(long studentId);

 }
```

**StudentServiceIMPL**

```
public String addStudent(StudentSaveDTO studentSaveDTO) {

    Student student = new Student(
        studentSaveDTO.getStudentId(),
        studentSaveDTO.getStudentName(),
        studentSaveDTO.getAddress(),
        studentSaveDTO.getMobile(),
        studentSaveDTO.getActiveState(),
    )

    studentRepo.save(student);

    return student.getStudentName();
}
public Student getStudent(long studentId) {

    return studentRepo.findById(studentId).get();
}
```

**TaskServiceIMPL**

```
public String addTask(TaskSaveDTO taskSaveDTO) {
    
    Student student = studentService.getStudent(taskSaveDTO.getStudentId());

    
    Task task = new Task(
            taskSaveDTO.getTaskname(),
            taskSaveDTO.getDescription(),
            taskSaveDTO.getComplete(),
            student
    );

    taskRepo.save(task);
    return task.getTaskname();
}
```

**Make sure to @autowire the StudentService in your TaskServiceIMPL.**

Comment: studentService.addStudent(student); this line error displayed change the 1 parameter of abstract method from studentDTO how to solve them

Comment: there........................................................

Comment: You have created StudentDTO?? Can you please provide StudentDTO, Student Entity?

Comment: this private Student student; is what?? Student is type of what?

Comment: Make sure this abstract method accepts Student Entity not Student DTO

String addStudent(Student student);

Comment: sir i update the student dto and entity please look at the code and solve my problem

Comment: Modified the answer recheck it!

Comment: Student student = studentService.addStudent(taskSaveDTO.getStudentSaveDTO()); in this line error displayed Change the variable type student type to string

Comment: Make sure addStudent() method returns Student        "Student addStudent(StudentSaveDTO studentSaveDTO);"

Comment: i added above the StudentServiceIMPL it is return student can you check it

Comment: Your StudentServiceIMPL must return Student object inorder to add that object in the Task Entity

Currently you are returning String which will not work in your case

Comment: so how to change String  to Student object

Comment: please help so how to change String to Student object i added code of StudentIMPL and StudentController Above please correct them

Comment: I've already added please once review it!

Comment: In student controller also return the Student object

Comment: public String saveStudent(@RequestBody StudentSaveDTO studentSaveDTO)
{
    String id = studentService.addStudent(studentSaveDTO);
    return id;
}     how to change as the object

Comment: I've also provided controller check!

Comment: ya. i correct it what you said i got the error after add the record of task java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.example.SpringAppliction.dto.StudentSaveDTO.getStudentname()" because "studentSaveDTO" is null

Comment: Provide me your input json

Comment: {
   
        "taskname" : "jkkk",
        "description": "sdfdsf",
        "complete": true,
        "student" : 2

}

Comment: Please add like these { "taskname" : "jkkk", "description": "sdfdsf", "complete": true, "studentSaveDTO" : {"studentid":1,"studentname":"Demo", "address":"Demo", "mobile":123, "activestate" : true} }

Comment: 023-07-22 17:34:53.726  WARN 14508 --- [nio-8070-exec-4] 023-07-22 17:34:53.726  WARN 14508 --- [nio-8070-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.SpringAppliction.dto.StudentSaveDTO` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (2);

Comment: Please correct the json

Comment: i did the json format what did you wrote.

Comment: {
   
       "taskname" : "jkkk", 
       "description": "sdfdsf", 
       "complete": true, 
       "studentSaveDTO" : 3

}

Comment: { 
"studentname":"dfdf",
 "address":"dsfsd", 
 "mobile":3434, 
 "activestate" : true


}

Comment: studentid is auto genterated as 3

Comment: Student will be generated with task only

Comment: Please add like these { "taskname" : "jkkk", "description": "sdfdsf", "complete": true, "studentSaveDTO" : {"studentid":1,"studentname":"Demo", "address":"Demo", "mobile":123, "activestate" : true} }

Comment: if i check in the postman work task and student both json run at one api it is works. why can't work student works separately and task works  separately

Comment: first register the student then add the task of them id

Comment: For that purpose you have to modify your entire logic when you accept id which is first generated using a different API then while inserting the task first you have to get the details of that particular id from the database and then you can only insert

Comment: ya student has @RequestMapping("api/v1/student")  api i made

Comment: and task has @RequestMapping("api/v1/task") i made

Comment: Okay then i've to modify the answer please provide both student repo and task repo i will modify my answer according to it

Comment: i added above please check it in your answer

Comment: Please add StudentRepo and TaskRepo

Comment: i added please check it now

Comment: done itttttttttttttttttt

Comment: thereeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: Edited Answer Check!

Comment: return studentRepo.findById(studentId);  this line of the code i got the error of
Optional
<com.example.SpringAppliction.entity.Student>

Comment: working but student table student id auto increment saving 1 3 5 like this format  another side task_id auto increment as 2 4 6 why not id is increament like this way

Comment: Because you are using strategy = GenerationType.AUTO instead use strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY .... and the drop the all tables and start again

Comment: ok GenerationType.IDENTITY is good instead of GenerationType.AUTO

Comment: Best Hard Worker He is very talented guy thanks for your time

Comment: one doubt GenerationType.IDENTITY is good instead of GenerationType.AUTO

Comment: Yes GenerationType.IDENTITY says let database handle the autogeneration of the primary keys where GenerationType.AUTO stands for hibernate will handle the generation of the primary key .. In this case hibernate generates hibernate_squence table to manage unique keys